# Python unsharp mask

Tags: python, opencv, numpy, image-processing, gaussian

I want to use `unsharp mask` on a 16 Bit Image.

The Image has `640 x 480 Pixels` and is saved in a NumPy array.

I have done the following:

- blurred the image with a `Gaussian filter` (three different methods)
- then, created a mask by subtracting the blur Image form the original
- finally, added the mask multiplied by `WightFaktor` to the original Image

But it doesn´t really work.

Here is the Python code:

```
Gaussian1 = ndimage.filters.gaussian_filter(Image,sigma=10.0)
Gaussian2 = filters.gaussian_filter(Image,sigma=10.0)
Gaussian3 = cv2.GaussianBlur(Image,(9,9),sigmaX=10.0)

Mask1 = Image - Gaussian1
UnsharpImage = Image + (WightFaktor*Mask1)
```

Answer (score 31):

To get an unsharp image using `OpenCV` you need to use the [addWeighted](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#addweighted) function as follows:

```
import cv2

image = cv2.imread("example.jpg")
gaussian_3 = cv2.GaussianBlur(image, (0, 0), 2.0)
unsharp_image = cv2.addWeighted(image, 2.0, gaussian_3, -1.0, 0)
cv2.imwrite("example_unsharp.jpg", unsharp_image)
```

Giving the following kind of result:

[image: mandrill unsharp example]

`addWeighted()` is used here as follows:

```
dst = cv2.addWeighted(src1, alpha, src2, beta, gamma)
```

Giving you the following transformation:

```
dst = src1*alpha + src2*beta + gamma
```

The strength of the effect can be altered by adjusting the `alpha` and `beta` weightings, for example: `1.5` and `-0.5`.

Comment: That is not a Gaussian filter, that's close to a uniform filter. See [this old blog post of mine](https://www.crisluengo.net/archives/695) for an explanation. Instead, use `cv2.GaussianBlur(image, (0,0), 10.0)` to let OpenCV compute the proper size of the kernel. But a sigma of 10 is way too large for this purpose, try 1 or 2 instead.

Comment: There are good arguments [link](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/full/10.1080/09500340.2016.1270881) that suggest the [mandrill](https://sipi.usc.edu/database/download.php?vol=misc&img=4.2.03), [peppers](https://sipi.usc.edu/database/download.php?vol=misc&img=4.2.07) might be  more encouraging of diversity and respect.

Answer (score 4):

One could use `scikit-image` or `PIL`'s `unsharp mask` implementation as well:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
from PIL import Image, ImageFilter
from skimage.io import imread
from skimage.filters import unsharp_mask
# with scikit-image
im = imread('images/lena.jpg')
im1 = np.copy(im).astype(np.float)
for i in range(3):
    im1[...,i] = unsharp_mask(im[...,i], radius=2, amount=2)
# with PIL
im = Image.open('images/lena.jpg')
im2 = im.filter(ImageFilter.UnsharpMask(radius=2, percent=150))
# plot
plt.figure(figsize=(20,7))
plt.subplot(131), plt.imshow(im), plt.axis('off'), plt.title('Original', size=20)
plt.subplot(132), plt.imshow(im1), plt.axis('off'), plt.title('Sharpened (skimage)', size=20)
plt.subplot(133), plt.imshow(im2), plt.axis('off'), plt.title('Sharpened (PIL)', size=20)
plt.show()
```

with the following output:

[image]

Also, adding some detailed stpes / comments on Martin Evans code with `opencv-python`:

```
import cv2

im = cv2.imread("images/lena.jpg")
im_blurred = cv2.GaussianBlur(im, (11,11), 10)
im1 = cv2.addWeighted(im, 1.0 + 3.0, im_blurred, -3.0, 0) # im1 = im + 3.0*(im - im_blurred)
plt.figure(figsize=(20,10))
plt.subplot(121),plt.imshow(cv2.cvtColor(im, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)), plt.axis('off'), plt.title('Original Image', size=20)
plt.subplot(122),plt.imshow(cv2.cvtColor(im1, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)), plt.axis('off'), plt.title('Sharpened Image', size=20)
plt.show()
```

[image]